# How to handle struct with procedural macro?

Tags: rust

I need dynamic handling of structure fields and their values. So, I need to dynamically read the name of the structure field and the value it contains for further processing. I understood how to get the name of the field, but I don’t quite understand how I can get the value that is stored in a specific field of the structure.

Something similar does the library **serde** and **validator**.

For example i have a struct:

```rust
#[derive(StackOverflow)]
struct User {
    email: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
}
```

And in another crate I create:

```rust
#[proc_macro_derive(StackOverflow, attributes(stackoverflow))]
pub fn derive_stackoverflow(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let ast = syn::parse(input).unwrap();
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can't access values at compile time with a proc macro. You have to generate code which does what you need. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Please be more clear in your question about what you're trying to do. Are you trying to implement a trait? Enforce some compile time check?

Comment: @PitaJ yes, I know. In my proc marco I want to create `impl` (in `quote!{}`) where will the function with `for` that iterate over all the names and values of the fields

Comment: It's usually advised to first write the code-to-be-generated by hand (for some example struct), to more clearly see how it should be structured and to check it actually works. If this won't help you to solve the problem, it will certainly help us to understand it.